# How to open an exported file through online docs when the user dont have a appropriate software in his desktop to open the file.. Pin

Tags: c#

In my application, am exporting the data from Grid to Excel file and save it in My Documents.

If the user dont have Excel installed in his machine, it has to redirect it to google spreadsheet to view the exported file..

Can any one tell me how to do it...

As of now, am displaying a message to the user if he dont have Excel installed in his machine to view the Exported Excel file, i want to replace this by redirecting it to Google spreadsheet to view the exported file, am using a code this code to display message to the user..

```
if (MessageBox.Show(
                        "Data Exported to File " + strFileName +
                        " at location MyDocuments. Do yo want to view the saved file?",
                        "Work Done",
                        MessageBoxButton.YesNo,
                        MessageBoxImage.Information) == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
                    {
                        Type officeType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Excel.Application");
                        if (officeType == null) 
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please Install MS Excel to view this file", "Liquidity Risk Management");
                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            olx.visible=true;
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Google Docs API. Fortunately, they have a .NET library for the same. http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html